# lunching icon no create

Tags: android

i facing some problem the lunching icon when i running finish the install the file but the lunching icon is not work. i think is i deleted the `Main_Activity`  by default, but i already at the `manifest` assign the intent default but still cant create the lunching icon.

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".CategoryActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android:intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You put a `:` within the `<action>` tag in the string.
Replace it by a `.` and it should work :

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
```